# SCSS not working correctly in Vite project

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, vite

I am currently working on a Vite project with React and SCSS. I am experiencing an issue where my SCSS is not being correctly applied to all pages. The SCSS seems to work fine on my home page, but when I navigate to other pages, the styles are not applied.

Here is a link to my project repository: https://github.com/Yhugzee/LiYhu-Studio

I have tried the following:

- Installing sass using yarn add -D sass
- Importing my main.scss file in App.jsx and main.jsx.
- Configuring my vite.config.js to include a path to my _variables.scss file.
- Importing my main.scss file in individual components.

Despite these attempts, I am still experiencing the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have compiled your main.scss,
in your App.jsx or main.jsx, you then import the compiled main.css at the top of the file. This applies a global style to all components.

In your App.jsx:

```
import './scss/main.css';
```

For component-specific styles, you create separate .scss (or .module.scss) files, compile them to .css, and then import these in the specific components where you want these styles applied.

In your Header.jsx or other specified components:

```
import './Header.module.css';
```

This way, your global styles are applied everywhere, and your component-specific styles are only applied to the specific components where you import them. You don't need to import the _variables.scss or main.scss file in every component, just in the main.scss file.

If you have your build tool (like Vite) configured to handle SCSS, it should take care of compiling your .scss files to .css and applying them correctly when you do the imports in your .jsx files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ^^

For the compilation of the SCSS I have file watcher on Intellij IDEA which takes care of the creation of the main.css and main.css.map files and my main.scss file contains the imports of my other .scss files and normally I don't need to import them into each component if they are already imported globally no?

Comment: Normally no, you don't need to import on each component unless the components have individual styles. The important part is that you import your compiled .css file to App.jsx, not the original .scss file.

Comment: Donc au lieu d'importer le fichier main.scss dans App.jsx, j'importe juste main.css et main.css.map ?

Comment: Only need to import main.css to App.jsx!
Main.css uses main.css.map to access main.scss.

Il suffit d'importer main.css dans App.jsx !
Main.css utilise main.css.map pour accéder à main.scss.

Comment: Thanks for replying in English and French I forgot to translate my msg ^^.

Unfortunately I imported main.css and it doesn't work :/. 

I don't know if it helps but in my browser I can't see which file the style comes from and it seems to double, look at https://imgur.com/a/rljdjuH

I don't know what to do...